# Getting a Date value from Oracle Stored Procedure using ODP.NET

Tags: c#, wpf, oracle, date, odp.net

I am hoping this is a simple one, as this is my first WPF with Oracle 11g (version 11.2). application.

I am able to call an Oracle stored procedures from my WPF application code and retrieve the  output (int and string) parameters, however when I try to retrieve a date value, I just get the following value `01/01/0001 00:00:00` which suggests a date is not actually being returned?

The stored procedure works fine in Oracle, i.e. it returns the date.

Here's my code:

```
string sql = "pkge_intautotest.ScheduleNextRun";
OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(sql, conn);
cmd.BindByName = true;
cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;

DateTime outSchedDateTime;
cmd.Parameters.Add("outSchedDateTime", OracleDbType.Date, ParameterDirection.Output);

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

//Get the values output by the stored procedure
outSchedDateTime = (DateTime)cmd.Parameters["outSchedDateTime"].Value;

conn.Close();
conn.Dispose();
```

And here's my (simplified) stored procedure:

```
PROCEDURE ScheduleNextRun (inIntno NUMBER, outCaseno OUT NUMBER, outSchedDateTime OUT DATE ) AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE
        sched_datetime DATE;
        init_diary_id DIARY.ID%TYPE;
        v_proceed PLS_INTEGER;

    BEGIN
        -- Get the schedule time for 4 minutes from now
        SELECT TO_DATE(SYSDATE + 4/(24*60)) INTO sched_datetime FROM dual;
        outSchedDateTime := sched_datetime;

    END;
END ScheduleNextRun;
```

I will continue looking at this, but any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is now working.

In my stored procedure, I had to change, the following line:

```
SELECT TO_DATE(SYSDATE + 4/(24*60)) INTO sched_datetime FROM dual;
```

To the following:

```
SELECT SYSDATE + 4/(24*60) INTO sched_datetime FROM dual;
```

Then as suggested by JMK, in my .NET code I had to change:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("outSchedDateTime", OracleDbType.Date, ParameterDirection.Output);
```

To the following:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("outSchedDateTime", OracleDbType.TimeStamp, ParameterDirection.Output);
```

So now in my WPF application, I can see the date and time portion. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I would try and get a string back from oracle initially, and then use DateTime.Parse to get this into a DateTime object, like this:

```
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

//Get the values output by the stored procedure
string rawDateTime = cmd.Parameters["outSchedDateTime"].Value.ToString();
var outSchedDateTime = DateTime.Parse(rawDateTime);
```

The reason you are only getting a Date back is because you are using the Date enumeration of [OracleDbType](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/win.102/b14307/OracleDbTypeEnumerationType.htm). I think if you changed this to TimeStamp, you would get a Date and a Time back:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("outSchedDateTime", OracleDbType.TimeStamp, ParameterDirection.Output);
```

Comment: Hi, thanks JMK, that's much better. I am seeing a date now, but not the time portion, e.g. '08/08/2013 00:00:00' for both the rawDateTime and outSchedDateTime variables.

Comment: Can you post an example of a DateTime you would get back from Oracle so we can see the format?

Comment: Yes, this what I'm getting back in Oracle: "08-08-2013 11:08:59". Cheers.

Comment: No, the content of rawDateTime is '08/08/2013 00:00:00'. That was the value returned from my stored procedure when running it in JB SQL.

Comment: No worries, I do appreciate your time on this. I have changed the stored procedure so that it now outputs a VARCHAR2 rather than a DATE, so, using your Timestamp suggestion I managed to get the date and time in .NET, although the hour was incorrect, so I'm still working on it. I think I might be close. Thanks again.

Comment: Just set the out paramater type to DBType.Date and get it back as a .net type.  The ODP.net provider will output .net types instead of Oracle types if required.  This document covers the details http://docs.oracle.com/html/B14164_01/featOraCommand.htm